# How to fix "Couldn't Attach File" when sharing image Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest, fileoutputstream

Im creating a application where a user can register and generate a qr code, after that they can save and share said generated QR image in their preferred medium(i.e. email, telegram, messenger, etc). Now I was able to save the QR image but everytime I try to share it this appear "Couldn't Attach File" message when im trying to send it thru gmail or cannot send image in other media. My expected output is that the image can be attached to the preferred medium of the user.

I have tried adding these in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and this but im not really sure what's this used for.

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/paths" />
</provider>
```

and this is my path.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="shared_images"
        path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

Lastly this is my java code for saving and sharing QR image

```
//Share function
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)qr_image.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap2 = drawable.getBitmap();

                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File Directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsoluteFile() + "/Download");
                Directory.mkdir();

                String filename = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                File outfile = new File(Directory, filename);
                File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + ".jpeg");
                Intent shareInt;

                try {
                    //save
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
                    bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(outfile));
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterStudent.this, "QR Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //share
                    shareInt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareInt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    shareInt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    shareInt.setType("image/jpeg");

                    shareInt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                    shareInt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "QR Code");
                    shareInt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please don't share your QR Code to anyone.");
                    shareInt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareInt, "Share image via"));
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Sorry this is my second time using stackoverflow if you have any questions or request that may help me fix my code please comment! Thank you!

Comment: Why is there a StrictMode? You asked this before. Try to share just a file the user picks from your device. I suggested that before.

Comment: And now your code is even worse as for obtaining a uri you cannot use Uri.fromFile().